# Report trends for sonarqube results

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like better insights on trends/reports of my sonarqube history. We're publishing results for a project per check in.

Is there any way to get a report of the code coverage over time or how test counts have increased over time?

Answer (score 0):

Version 6.5 offers activity graphs. There are a few canned ones, and also the ability to roll your own with the metrics of your choice. [Here's a Coverage graph](https://sonarcloud.io/project/activity?custom_metrics=coverage&graph=custom&id=be.yildiz-games%3Acommon-client) for a project chosen at random:

[image: Coverage graph]

If that doesn't do it for you, then the [Measures History web service](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures/search_history) is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks, do you have to rev the version of the project each scan to get that history?